# WPF свойство меняется только при входе в программу

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, binding

Делаю WPF приложение используя MVVM паттерн, есть такой код
Свойство которое нужно постоянно менять в форме:

```
public decimal Seconds
{
    get
    {
        if (_stopwatchModel.Elapsed.HasValue)
            return _stopwatchModel.Elapsed.Value.Seconds + (_stopwatchModel.Elapsed.Value.Milliseconds * .001M);
        else
            return 0.0M;
    }
}
```

Запускаю таймер

```
_dispatcherTimer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(50);
_dispatcherTimer.Tick += TimerTick;
_dispatcherTimer.Start();
```

Что происходит на тик таймера:

```
private void TimerTick(object sender, object e)
{
    if (_lastSeconds != Seconds)
        _lastSeconds = Seconds;
}
```

В `xaml` у меня такое:

```
<TextBlock Margin="5 5">
    <Run Text="{Binding Seconds, Mode=OneWay}" />
</TextBlock>
```

Текст отображается 1 раз при начале программы, а нужно, чтобы было постоянное изменение, понимаю, что проблема в `OneWay` но не знаю как это поправить

Comment: Проблема не в `OneWay`, а в том, что вы не оповещаете об изменениях свойства. Почитайте про INotifyPropertyChanged

Comment: @АндрейNOP Я реализовал `INotifyPropertyChanged`, так как меняю свойство в `ViewModel` классе

Comment: Я не вижу этого в вашем коде. Покажите как вы оповещаете о том, что значение свойства изменилось и его пора бы перечитать?

Comment: @АндрейNOP ну тем что я реальзовал интерфейс INotifyPropertyChanged, или вы про то, что у меня нет OnPropertyCahnged? Я использую FodyWeaver, чтобы его не писать, или про что вы?

Comment: Fody это хорошо, но только что оно даст для свойства, не имеющего сеттера? Вам нужно в методе `TimerTick` как-то оповестить GUI о том, что свойство `Seconds` изменилось и его надо перечитать

Comment: @АндрейNOP понял свою ошибку, но как ее исправить? Добавить OnPropertyChanged в момент, где нужно изменение свойства?

Comment: Да, вызвать метод, оповещающий об изменениях в нужном месте. Типа `FireNotifyPropertyChanged(nameof(Seconds));`

Comment: @АндрейNOP заработало, спасибо, пожалуй почитаю еще про изменение свойств, так как видимо понял не до конца с: Где тут можно отметить ваш ответ как правильный?

Comment: Моего ответа тут нет, есть только комментарии, их принять в качестве ответа нельзя. Напишите ответом то что сделали самостоятельно.

Comment: @АндрейNOP Понял, добавил ответ, а ваш коммент плюсанул, еще раз спасибо за ответ

Answer (score 0):

Из ответов в комментариях под постом получил нужный мне ответ, нужно вызвать метод, оповещающий об изменениях, т.е. `OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Seconds))` в нужном месте.